# Array.Exists for boolean comparison in integer array (converted from string)

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm trying to find if certain values in a given string of numbers are less than a numeric value.

I'm trying to create a new integer array and iterate through the string array to fill it. Then I'm trying to use [Array.Exists(arr, predicate)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.array.exists?view=net-5.0), but I don't think I'm using it correctly.

I wasn't able to simply do `Array.Exists(larr, element => element <=16)` because my compiler required I have parentheses like `Array().Exists(larr, element...)` or `Array(larr).Exists(lar, element...)`.

What would you recommend changing in my code so that I can transform a string into an array of numbers or some other data structure that will allow me to check if any value within it is <=some value?

```
    Dim orgnameB As Range
    Dim orgList As Range
    Set orgList = Worksheets("Org List").Range("B3:B10")
    sites = Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB.row, "E")
    max_num = Evaluate("Max(" & sites & ")")
    sarr = Split(sites, ", ")
    Dim ArrayLen As Integer
    ArrayLen = UBound(sarr) - LBound(sarr) + 1 'this was causing issues, unsure how to do this
    Dim larr(ArrayLen) As Integer

    Set result = Worksheets("Org List").Cells(orgnameB.row, "O")
    'Loop through str array to convert to int array
    For i = LBound(sarr) To UBound(sarr)
        larr(i) = CInt(sarr(i))
    Next i

    For Each orgnameB In orgList
    If IsEmpty(orgnameB) = True Then
        Exit For
    End If
    If max_num >= 1 And max_num <= 15 Then
        result.Value = "YES"
    ElseIf max_num >= 16 And max_num <= 50 Then
        If Array(larr).Exists(larr, element => element <= 16) = True Then
            result.Value = "YES"
        End If
    ElseIf max_num >= 51 And max_num <= 250 Then
        If Array(larr).Exists(larr, element => element <= 51) = True Then
        result.Value = "YES"
        End If
    ElseIf max_num >= 251 And max_num <= 1000 Then
        If Array(larr).Exists(larr, element => element <= 250) = True Then
        result.Value = "YES"
        End If
    ElseIf max_num >= 1001 Then
        If Array(larr).Exists(larr, element => element <= 1000) = True Then
            result.Value = "YES"
        End If
    End If
    Next

    End Sub
```

Comment: You're confusing VBA and VB.net. `Array.Exists` is .Net, and as such not applicable to VBA.

Comment: `=>` - you probably meant `>=`.

Comment: BigBen is correct. You would first have to import the .NET `Array` implementation. If it's not already COM visible you would need to write your own COM visible wrapper for it and then import that.

Comment: If you need to check for the existance of an element in VBA you can use a `Scripting.Dictionary` object. https://excelmacromastery.com/vba-dictionary/

Answer (score 0):

**`FilterXML()` as VBA simulation of `Array.Exists()`:**

Of course *Excel VBA* cannot apply specific *.Net* or *C* syntax.

Therefore the following example demonstrates how to rebuild a similar functionality (returning `True` for existant array findings) via the **`FilterXML()`** function which allows to specify **multiple conditions**.

It offers the *extra benefit*, however that it doesn't return only a boolean value, but that it returns all found (numeric) elements as 0-based 1-dim *output array*
which can be analyzed and/or reused easily eventually.

**Example call**

```
    Dim InArray() As Variant, limits() As Variant, OutArray() As Variant
    InArray = Array(10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)
    
    limits = Array(9)               ' find elements <= 9
    Debug.Print "Array exists: " & ArrExists(InArray, limits, OutArray), UBound(OutArray) + 1 & " Element(s) ~> " & Join(OutArray, ",")
    '            Array exists: False        0 Element(s) ~>

    limits = Array(13)                      ' find elements <= 13
    Debug.Print "Array exists: " & ArrExists(InArray, limits, OutArray), UBound(OutArray) + 1 & " Element(s) ~> " & Join(OutArray, ",")
    '            Array exists: True         4 Element(s) ~> 10,11,12,13
    
    limits = Array(11, 13)                  ' find elements >=11 and <= 13
    Debug.Print "Array exists: " & ArrExists(InArray, limits, OutArray), UBound(OutArray) + 1 & " Element(s) ~> " & Join(OutArray, ",")
    '            Array exists: True         3 Element(s) ~> 11,12,13
End Sub
```

**Help Function `ArrExists()**

The following functions profits from filtering a well formed XML content by
a so called XPath expression, which is available since vers. 2013+.

Note that findings are automatically assigned to a 2-dim array, only non-findings result in an error value.
In order to return results again to a "flat" 1-dim output array, they need to be transposed.

```
Function ArrExists(InArray, limits, Optional OutArray) As Boolean
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '1.   define FILTERXML arguments
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '  a) build Xml content
    Dim XmlContent As String
    XmlContent = "<items><i>" & Join(InArray, "</i><i>") & "</i></items>"
    '  b) build XPath expression
    Dim XPathExpression As String
    If UBound(limits) Then
        If limits(1) > limits(0) Then
            XPathExpression = "//i[.>=" & limits(0) & "][.<=" & limits(1) & "]"
        Else
            XPathExpression = "//i[.>=" & limits(1) & "][.<=" & limits(0) & "]"
        End If
    Else
        XPathExpression = "//i[.<=" & limits(0) & "]"
    End If
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '2.   apply FILTERXML() function
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'a) get results as 2-dim array
    Dim results: results = Application.FilterXML(XmlContent, XPathExpression)
    'b) check for no result or one result only
    If Not IsArray(results) Then
        If IsError(results) Then
           ReDim results(0 To 0, 1 To 1)
        Else
            Dim tmp As Variant: tmp = results
            ReDim results(1 To 1, 1 To 1)
            results(1, 1) = tmp
        End If
    End If
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '3.Function results
    '~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'a)return existence as boolean value
    If LBound(results) Then ArrExists = True
    
    'b)optional: overwrite referenced array
    If Not IsMissing(OutArray) Then
        If ArrExists Then
            OutArray = Application.Transpose(results)          ' results now 1-based
            ReDim Preserve OutArray(0 To UBound(OutArray) - 1) ' redim as zero-based
        Else
            ReDim OutArray(-1 To -1)
        End If
    End If
End Function
```